# Who is the author of Romanoff's theorem?

Tags: mathematics

This is the theorem in mathematics. This link [Romanoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanov%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20specifically%20additive%20number,a%20positive%20lower%20asymptotic%20density.) provides that the first proof was around 1934 and the proof was by    Nikolai Pavlovich Romanov.
But when I searched for "Nikolai Pavlovich Romanov" I got [Nikolai Pavlovich Romanov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_I_of_Russia) as the first reference but in the site he died in 1855 so this is confusing for me.

Could anyone provide the biography of Nikolai Pavlovich Romanov? Who was him?

Comment: This looks like it would be a better fit at [History of Math and Science Stackexchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7):

See Romanov's brief bio in the Wikipedia article [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA)). Use Google translate if you cannot read Russian. Note that there appears to be a small error in the article. Namely, according to the book "Thirty Years of mathematics in USSR, 1917-1947", p. 57, Romanov's advisor was Schnirelmann, not Khinchin and Schmidt as Wikipedia says.